# How to get callback function result from FormRequest object

Tags: python, scrapy

Use scrapy to parse site, and  need parse dropdown menu's for final request.

FormRequest class use for post request to dropdown menu to get list of options next dropdown menu using  callback function

```
scrapy.FormRequest(url = make_url, formdata=data1, callback=self.parse_make)

def parse_make(self, response):
        data = response.text.split(',')
        datac=[]
        for row in data:
            row = row.split(':')[1].replace('"','')
            print(row)
            datac.append(row)
        return datac
```

Need to get datac list, for next parcing iteration

Comment: are you looking to pass the "datac" to another function?

Comment: yes  i would like  use it in another  function

Comment: well there are plenty of ways to do it, you can simply use `self.function(datac)` or call spider closed and write your function into `spider_closed`